# Regex in Java to read everything till a full stop?

Tags: java, regex

I have some full stops (periods .) in between the sentences and I don't want to split the text based on . before applying the regex. 
I have regex to parse/read the starting part of sentence, then I want to read one ore many words till I encounter a period. Please suggest.

Example:

`Input : Figure 4-9 illustrates this situation.`

`Output {Figure} {4.9} {illustrates this situation}`

Comment: `String#split` will split it for you on the delimiter `.`, also please show your attempt to better illustrate your description.

Comment: can you share an example input output and your code please

Comment: Show your regex. Splitting the input by periods is all you have to do by the way ;)

Comment: {Figure} {4.9} {illustrates this situation}.
It is an example sentence. I have put the brackets around the parts that I want as output.

Comment: @Aominè be careful with `split(".")` as the parameter to `split()` will be a regex. Thus it'd have to be `split("\\.")`.

Comment: Rules are not clear in forming `{Figure} {4.9} {illustrates this situation}`

Comment: @iota please add that to your question ([edit] it) and not as a comment. And as revo said, we'd need the input as well and if you can a description of which rules _you'd_ apply.

Comment: @Thomas true, I just didn't want to write a full answer within the comments, but once OP shows their attempt, then maybe it would be a good time to provide a valid solution ^^.

Comment: This is my attempt "(Figure)(\\s)(\\d+\\.\\d+)(\\s+)([^.]+)";

Answer (score 0):

After your starting part pattern put spaces (`\s+`) and then anything up to a period would match the desired words. The latter may be put as "any char but a period one or more times", which in regex is written as `[^.]+`. The final regex:

```
(Figure)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([^.]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8O0yuQ/1